# Disabling Nagle's Algorithm under Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I've been working with AS3 sockets, and I noticed that small packets are 'Nagled' when sent. I tried to find a way to set NoDelay for the socket, but I didn't find a clue even in the documentation. Is there another way to turn Nagle'a algorithm off in AS3 TCP sockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell Flash to send out the data through the socket using the [Flush](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html#flush%28%29) method on the socket Object.

> Flushes any accumulated data in the socket's output buffer.

That said, flash does what it thinks is the better, and may doesn't want to send your data too often. Still, that shouldn't be over few milliseconds.